# Why does Felix burn his own church at the end of Messiah Season 1

Tags: messiah

At the end of final episode of "Messiah" Season 1 On Netflix, after all about this "Messiah dude" are revealed by FBI authorities on local TV news, he suddenly go into his church in Texas and pouring the gasoline and burn his own church. I don't understand why he did it at the final episode of Messiah. Could someone explain to me why Felix did it ?

Comment: Does this show contain any elements of Science Fiction or Fantasy? It appears to be about a man who may or may not be some kind of illusionist.

Comment: @Valorum skimming google suggests that the final episode suggests actual supernatural powers, not just tricks. Without having seen it I'd defer to someone who has.

Answer (score 1):

I can try. I'm still trying to figure out why myself. [Spoilers  ahead] I think the fact that he planned to burn it down before but changed his mind when al-Masih (Payam) came to town might hold some insight. Remember  the family had financial troubles. Felix was looking for an easy way out, his faith was waning, so he decided to burn down the church for the insurance money but stopped on account of the tornado(note, the church is the only structure  left standing, fully  in tact - all the houses and businesses were destroyed). This strange prophet blows into town with the tornado and does some "apparently" miraculous things, plus the church still standing after the devastation, ta-da faith restored (not to mention the inferiority complex he's contending with that probably put $$ in his eyes).

Then, when Payam was discredited in the media (among other events), Felix had no reason to carry on the farce, faith is back to zero.

With all that happening, burning down the church can make sense for 3 possible reasons:

1. He's gonna need that money from insurance claims on the church since people might not be picking up the phone to interview (and pay) him for his **superior** perspective on the divine (also, remember the tornado destroyed everything in the town except the church).

[You could say this is related, but I also want to point out whenever Felix is about to make some grand gesture or give a big speech, something undercuts him. It's almost comedic. He just can't get a break lol.]

2. He was attempting to reassert that control he was craving, and at the same time, sticking it to God for not giving him the prestige and glory he was looking for in his relationship with Payam. OR

[I suppose it shouldn't  come as a surprise that felix jumped at the opportunity to lead the caravan into the unknown without knowing much of the situation. Yes, we could say it was just blind faith or potential manipulation from Payam. Nevertheless, I think, as a pastor, Felix was trying to satisfy that need to be seen as the guy to be revered and respected.]

3. The church is the last standing monument to Felix's old ways of thinking and being, this action of destroying the church could be a symbol of his choice to become something else, start fresh maybe.

Here endeth my interpretation. I Hope it helps.